# How to create a custom share button in Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk, fbsdksharekit

I try to create custom share Button in Facebook SDK, but I have a problem with it. Following Facebook documentation, share Button in my case looks like that:

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentTitle = "\(postTitle)"
content.contentURL = NSURL(string:"\(www)")

let shareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
shareButton.shareContent = content
shareButton.center = selfview.center
self.view.addSubiview(shareButton)
```

it works, but I have a default button, which doesn't look good in my layout. I would like to have a possibility share my content using my own button `facebookShareButton: UIButton`. Do I have a possibility to call this action in my own button? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution for this problem:

We need to create an UIButton outlet for example `@IBOutlet weak var facebookOutlet: UIButton!` and then add code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
  facebookOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.postFacebook(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Then in `viewDidAppear()` we need to add:

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
content.contentTitle = "\(postTitle)"
content.contentURL = NSURL(string:"\(www)")

let shareButton = FBSDKShareButton()
shareButton.shareContent = content
shareButton.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(shareButton)
```

Then in action of our button we need to add:

```
func postFacebook(sender: UIButton){
    shareButton.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
}
```

It works perfect and allow us to create a custom facebook button.

Comment: thanks, `sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)` – the main point.

Comment: how will you access 'shareButton' in postfacebook method?? @PiterPan

Comment: define `let shareButton = FBSDKShareButton()` as class property, then you will have a possibility to use it in fun scope @Aashish

Answer (score 0):

With the latest FBSDKShareKit, you can add the below to your custom button's action handler

```
let dialog = ShareDialog()
dialog.shareContent = content
dialog.show()
```